# What does this code means?(VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net

```
        For I = 1 To Len(InputString)
        If InStr(InputString, Mid(Vowels, I, 1)) Then
            nVowels = nVowels + 1
        End If
    Next
```

I'm new and trying my best to learn this language :) Thanks in advance :)
Anyways, that is a part of my code where it counts the number of vowels in a given string.

Comment: Which line are you referring to?  [`Len`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxsw58z6(v=vs.90).aspx), [`InStr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx) and [`Mid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05e63829(v=vs.90).aspx) are all fully documented...

Comment: Len, InStr and Mid, all these are VB6 compatible methods provided in vb.net, consider not to use them. Since you are learning vb.net, go for a better example.

Comment: Check the `InStr` documentation. I think you mean `InStr(Vowels, Mid(InputString, I, 1))`. Better still, take Sarvesh's advice and read [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Whether or not you use the `Contains` method as suggested, you also need to change the end of your first line to `Len(Vowels)`. As written, your code will never find a vowel in words such as "I", "in", "to", "mud", "book", etc.

Comment: @Josh - That would be OK if we were counting the number of distinct vowels. E.g. InputString = "caravan"? What should nVowels be? 1 or 3?

Comment: @Fruitbat, you're right - the intent is unclear. It's up to Juju to decide which behavior he wants and choose which correction to use.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, except for a small mistake: you swapped the parameters of `InStr` function..

Assuming you have

```
Dim Vowels As String
Vowels = "aeiou"
```

Your current code will not work for words like `"Sun"`. Here is why:

1- Your for loop will be initialized to count from 1 to 3 (length of "Sun")

2- You are checking if "Sun" contains the first character of Vowels (a).
3- Check if "Sun" contains the next character of Vowels (e).
4- Check if "Sun" contains the next character of Vowels (i).

5- Loop exit (i=3).

So the logic needs to be re-written to work the other way around:

```
 For I = 1 To Len(InputString)
        If InStr(UCase(Vowels), Mid(UCase(InputString), I, 1)) Then
            nVowels = nVowels + 1
        End If
 Next
```